# org-mode:differences between TODO and sentence with date (and time) only

Tags: org-mode

I made on my .org file two lines:

1)

```
** TODO somethings <22-09-29 Thu 10:15>
```

2. 

```
** somethings <22-09-29 Thu 11:15>
```

If I type `C-c a` to enter in agenda views, I find both the entry 1) and 2) with no differences.
So, I'm wondering: what are the differences between them?

Comment: One is in TODO state, the other isn't: that's literally the only difference. That means that both will appear in the weekly agenda (because of the date - and assuming that the file is on the agenda file list), but only the first one will appear in the TODO list (`C-c a t` if you follow the keybinding convention in the manual).

Comment: That is what I suspected... and...that is! Thank you!